# Why do I get error when i pass a valid json in webservice via ajax request in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, ajax

I have written the following code in angularjs in a function:

```
var json={"a":"a"};
$http({
method: 'POST',
url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/send',
headers: {
'Content-type': 'application/json'
},
data: json
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
alert(response);
});
```

when i call this function i get the Error: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" in browser console.

Although i get the json in the backend(web service send). 
Why do i get this error in browser?

thank you

Comment: What is the character it is complaining about? Is your webservice definitely returning JSON?

Answer (score 0):

This request code is completely fine, just as described in the spec even. That error is thrown when a non-string (probably a json object) is passed to the JSON.parse method somewhere or another.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your webservice isn't returning json or throwing an error. Can you make the same call to your service using something like [DevHttpClient](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en) or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) works and returns valid json?

I would also try setting the accept header to tell the service you want to retrieve json back as a response in case it's defaulting to xml. e.g

```
...<snip>...
headers: {
'Content-type': 'application/json'
'Accept': 'application/json'
},
...<snip>...
```